# Full list of Photoshop Shortcuts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, cs5, shortcuts

I want to build on my Photoshop performance and a key solution would be to learn the shortcuts for Photoshop.  That said does anyone know a **reliable** place to get Photoshop CS5 and CS6 shocrtcuts listed??

**EDIT**
The shortcut to the shortcut list is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Also upon review thanks to @John.  In Illustrator CS4, CS5 and CS6 also has the shortcut list and the shortcut list is in CS4, CS5 and CS6, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most reliable source for Photoshop shortcuts is going to be Photoshop itself. You can export your shortcuts to an HTML document:

Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts, click `Summarize`.

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

You should then be prompted where to save the HTML page which will show you all your shortcuts in a nice list.

[image: Photoshop Shortcuts List]

This list can be quite extensive and you probably won't use them all. If you are more of a visual learner, run an image search for something like "[photoshop keyboard layout](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=785&q=photoshop+keyboard+layout)" and you'll see the most popular/useful default shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a list of shortcuts for PS CS5 available as a PDF, just click this text.](http://creativealive.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/adobe-photoshop-CS5-keyboard-shortcuts.pdf)

Here's an example of how it looks - there are far too many to screenshot them all:

[image: Screenshot of Photoshop shortcuts PDF]